# What is the exact material brand and model number of Lego (ABS)?

Tags: materials

Can anyone tell me the exact ABS material (brand and number) used for Lego?

Is it food grade material?

Kind regards

Comment: Probably a company secret.

Comment: Ask the company. This is not a chemistry question, please delete.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not germane to this site

Comment: See another Stachexchange for a good discussion on the topic: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7471/bpa-in-older-lego This article from the WSJ suggests - food grade perhaps not.
https://www.wsj.com/articles/lego-struggles-to-find-a-plant-based-plastic-that-clicks-11560331800